# Scrapy - How to scrape a data that doesn't appear in the source code?

Tags: python, scrapy

I started to learn about scrapy a week ago without knowing anything about python or even coding. However, I think I understand scrapy logic. 
I'm trying to extract some data from this website: 
https://www.unibet.fr/sport/football/ligue-2, which is a sports betting website.

I would like to scrape the bet for each match of the soccer French league 2. For instance, for the Auxerre-Châteauroux encounter, I want the following numbers: `1.92`, `3.30`, `4.10`.
Nevetheless, these numbers seem to be missing in the source code of the page. However, when I right click on `Auxerre - Châteauroux` to inspect the elements I found these numbers.

But it seems I cannot have access to these numbers with the URL mentioned above. Moreover, when I run scrapy shell with this URL, I obtain the following result:

```
>>> fetch("https://www.unibet.fr/sport/football/ligue-2")
2017-12-08 15:37:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-12-08 15:37:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unibet.fr/sport/football/ligue-2> (referer: None)

>>> view(response)
True
```

How can I access these numbers in the page source?

Comment: page use JavaScript to display data, and Scrapy doesn't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which will run JavaScript. Or you have to use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox to find url which is used by JavaScript to get data. And the you can use this url to get data too. Many times JavaScript gets data as JSON which Python can easily convert into python's `dictionary` (using module `json`)

Comment: Fix English language and code formatting